# Manage duplicate subdocuments in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Have 2 models.

1. User
2. Plants

End user should be able to add multiple quantities of same plant.
My User model is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    cart: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Plants',
    }
    ],
    address: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Contacts'
    }]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

My Plants model is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const plantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Plants', plantSchema)
```

Want my user to contain multiple duplicate subdocuments for plants.

```
0:6013ab17e5d05b3457cf983a
1:6017ce139e9f3d6d3a616f2b
2:6017ce139e9f3d6d3a616f2b
3:6017ce139e9f3d6d3a616f2b
4:6017ce139e9f3d6d3a616f2b
5:6017ce139e9f3d6d3a616f2b
```

How should I manage this

Answer (score 1):

Use the populate function of mongoose.Document

```js
const doc = await User.findById(id).populate('cart');
```

You can choose to populate multiple fields in the document by;

```js
const docs = await User.findById(id).populate('cart').populate('address');
```

Use this link to read more
[Mongoose populate document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)

Answer (score 0):

Every subdocument has its own _id which is generated automatically when you push a Plants document to User document. Which means, 2 same plants would appear with different _id's when you list the User document. Try using

```
const result = await User.find({}).populate('cart');
```

This will populate your cart and show you the Plants which have been pushed as subdocuments to your User document